# た くみ or 匠 or たくみ

Tags: translation, resources

た くみ (notice space) is translated by Google Translate as 'take it easy'

匠 as 'master' or 'artisan'.

たくみ  as 'Takumi'

I don't find any evidence besides Google Translate that た くみ can be 'take it easy'. Other dictionaries also don't show the 'master' translation.

Is Google Translate wrong here (again)? I'm inclined to assume that 匠 is 'artisan' (unless in the combination 巨匠, which would be a master) たくみ would be the proper name 'Takumi'.

Am I right?

How careful should I be with Google Translate?

Comment: What made you specifically look up "た くみ" with the space in it?

Comment: たくみ could be 巧み; a na-adjective, one of whose translations is 'masterful'. I have no idea about "た　くみ". Google translate stinks at Japanese. You should not trust it at all.

Comment: @HansPeter: it's how a Japanese restaurant in Marbella, Spain writes its name https://www.restaurantetakumi.com. They also write ta-kumi, which Google translates as 'Tak look'

Answer (score 4):

This is a good example of how important context is. たくみ is a play on words, as they [explain on their webpage](https://www.restaurantetakumi.com/):

> El nombre Takumi representa la esencia del restaurante, “artesano”, “maestro”, además de la unión de los dos prestigiosos chefs, Toshio y Álvaro (TA) en el mismo equipo (Kumi), un juego de palabras perfecto que compone el espíritu del restaurante Ta-Kumi Gastro-Bar.

With the help of what little I know about Spanish and Google Translate (yes, it can be useful, if used right), that loosely translates to

> The name Takumi represents the essence of this restaurant - “artesano”, “maestro”. It also stands for the name of its two prestigious chefs, Toshio and Álvaro (Ta, た), who form a team (Kumi, 組). A perfect word game that makes up the spirit of the Ta-Kumi Gastro-Bar restaurant.

So their claims are:

- たくみ means artisan, which is right (see below).
- Takumi can also mean "maestro", a Spanish word that, [according to wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=maestro&oldid=51940398), means (among other things) "(master) craftsman". Apparently, by itself "maestro" can be ambigious, which is why they paired it with "artesano" - to clarify the meaning of たくみ. It does not translate to all the nuances and meanings of the English word "master"
- くみ (組) can refer to a team or group of several persons, which is also true. For example,  2人組 refers to a team or group of two people, such as a team of two comedians.

As for Google Translate and the translation "take it easy": It does somewhat well if you give it well-formed Japanese sentences (that do not involve poetry or too much creative language usage). You should not expect software to be able to translate a word without context, especially when it involves word play.

Just compare these results from Google Translate:

- `た くみ?` becomes `Are you tired?`
- `た,くみ` becomes `Sun, eyes`
- `た くみ` becomes `Take it easy`
- `た くみ!` becomes `Take it!`

Thinking about it, this could become a new homebrew encryption for English text...

---

From the Japanese-English dictionary 新和英大辞典 第5版:

Excerpt from the entry for たくみ:

> たくみ(meaning no. 2)【匠･工】 (takumi)
>
> 1 〔細工師〕 an artisan; a craftsman; a workman; a mechanic; 〔木工〕 a woodworker; a carpenter; a joiner
>
> [...]

Excerpt from the entry for くみ:

> くみ(meaning no. 1)【組】
>
> [...]
>
> グループ〕 a party; a group; a team; (競技の) a team; (こぎ手の) a crew;
>
> [...]
>
> 2組に分ける　divide 《the class》 into two groups [teams]

Comment: Besides the restaurant proper and google translate, do you have any source for takumi meaning master/maestro?

Comment: Yes, see the end of the post that quotes from a [well-known Japanese-English dictionary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenkyusha%27s_New_Japanese-English_Dictionary).

Comment: The pasted bit does not say it means maestro. This dictionary might have 師匠 - ししょう as master, teacher or 巨匠 - きょしょう as master, masterhand. But plain  匠 - たくみ won't mean maestro by itself.

Comment: Exactly. I was talking about the Spanish word `maestro` in the sense of `(master) craftsman` (which is what that restaurant is referring to), not about the English word `maestro` in the sense of `a great performer, especially a musician`; nor about the English word `master` with its many senses.